# Star rating not showing up in Google results, but in testing tool works fine

Tags: schema, rating

So I have this problem, I've done all changes need and suggested by google, and still I don't get those stars under my search since my articles have rating system and it's all packed.

It does show it in google test tool alright but in actual google results it's just simple result block with no extra stuff that I've marked-up, one of those being star rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea if you could post a URL of a page that you've marked up so that we could take a look.  It's still possible to have technical errors in your markup, and it's also possible that your markup does not meet Google's guidelines, even if the testing tool shows no errors.  But even if your markup is technically perfect and it meets Google's guidelines, there are no guarantees that Google will display your rich snippets in the SERPs.  Google uses a number of various quality signals to determine if, when, and which rich snippets to display for a page.

But again, if you could share a URL with us, we could at least take a closer look at things.  Thanks.